# Random point inside a circle

Tags: geometry

A point inside a circle of radius $\sqrt{50}$ lies $2$ units directly below a point on the circle, and $6$ units directly to the
right of a point on the circle. What is the distance from
the center of the circle to this point?

Can't find anything, this was rated as an easy question so i think there will be just one concept for this. I tried power of a point and and coordinate geometry but I cant answer it

Answer (score 2):

Let the centre of the circle be at the origin, and let the point have coordinates $(p,q)$. Then $p^2+(q+2)^2=50 \ \text{(eq. 1)}$, and $(p-6)^2+q^2=50 \ \text{(eq. 2)}$, so $p^2+(q+2)^2=(p-6)^2+q^2 \ \text{(eq. 3)} $.

Expanding, we have:

$$p^2+q^2+4q+4=p^2-12p+36+q^2$$
$$4q+4=-12p+36$$
$$q+1=-3p+9$$
$$q=-3p+8 \ \text{(eq. 4)}$$

You can then substitute back into equation $1$ to find $p$. Then you can use equation $2$ and subtract $-12p+36$ from the LHS to find $p^2+q^2$, then $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$.

Comment: You might want to start off by saying, let the center of the circle be at the origin.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fixed.